# Could not login into TailScale during Ubuntu auto installation

Tags: cloud-init, autoinstall, user-data

Initially Ive tried official TailScale [config](https://tailscale.com/kb/1293/cloud-init):

```
#cloud-config
# The above header must generally appear on the first line of a cloud config
# file, but all other lines that begin with a # are optional comments.

runcmd:
  # One-command install, from https://tailscale.com/download/
  - ['sh', '-c', 'curl -fsSL https://tailscale.com/install.sh | sh']
  # Set sysctl settings for IP forwarding (useful when configuring an exit node)
  - ['sh', '-c', "echo 'net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.d/99-tailscale.conf && echo 'net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.d/99-tailscale.conf && sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/99-tailscale.conf" ]
  # Generate an auth key from your Admin console
  # https://login.tailscale.com/admin/settings/keys
  # and replace the placeholder below
  - ['tailscale', 'up', '--authkey=tskey-abcdef1432341818']
  # Optional: Include this line to make this node available over Tailscale SSH
  - ['tailscale', 'set', '--ssh']
  # Optional: Include this line to configure this machine as an exit node
  - ['tailscale', 'set', '--advertise-exit-node']
```

After Ubuntu server installation were complete and restarted I was not able to find tailscale program in terminal. Even though tailscale online admin console shows that new node actually were added but is now offline.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/rossedman/87abb57aafb53030e881b410ea66ba4b#file-userdata-tpl) is quite helpfull link with example of user-data which installs TailScale during Ubuntu Server autoinstall:

```
#cloud-config
---
apt:
  sources:
    tailscale.list:
      source: deb https://pkgs.tailscale.com/stable/ubuntu focal main
      keyid: 2596A99EAAB33821893C0A79458CA832957F5868
packages: 
  - tailscale
runcmd:
  - [tailscale, up, -authkey, ${tailscale_key}]
```

And after installation of Ubuntu and system restart I am able to find TailScale program on the system. But authentication part:

```
runcmd:
  - [tailscale, up, -authkey, ${tailscale_key}]
```

does not work, and TailScale status is *logged out*.

I have tried several other ways to workaround this but with no success:

```
runcmd:
  - [tailscale, up, -authkey, tskey-client-ffffffff, --advertise-tags=tag: server, --advertise-exit-node, --ssh, --operator=oleh]
```

```
late-commands:
  - sudo curtin in-target --target=/target -- /usr/bin/tailscale up -authkey tskey-client-ggggggg # --advertise-tags=tag:server --advertise-exit-node --ssh --operator=oleh
```

Also tried to add login command to crontab and systemd.

Question is, how to login to the TailScale during autoinstall or after first reboot?